# What are the most important environmental conditions that affect vegetable production?

Tags: vegetables, growth, optimal-conditions, greenhouse

What do you feel are the most important environmental conditions that affect vegetable production in a greenhouse?

Comment: Bit of a broad question so the answer has to be broad too - water, temperature and light.

Comment: Welcome to the site! This question is very general, so the answers you get are not likely to be very specific. If that's all you need, that's fine, but adding some more details to your question will help you (and future readers) learn more. For instance: What vegetables do you plan to grow?  What's your general climate? Do you intend to start them in the greenhouse, then transplant into the garden? What type of greenhouse is it? Have you checked out our [help]? I like to start with the [ask] page. We hope you have fun here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nutrients, heat, humidity, water and light.

Answer (score 1):

Airflow to prevent moulds - 
adequate ventilation, some seeds germinate better when cool, others won't if they get hot.  Basic research will tell you what conditions your seeds or plants would like.